# Batch rename files in Python 2.7

Tags: python, append, rename

I'm trying to rename files in a directory so that it the new name is the original name followed by a space + "17-" + an incrementally increasing number.

The code below is just renaming files from 151, upward. How do I keep the original name, adding the text "17-" and the numbers?

```
import os
path = 'C:\Users\dcs\Desktop\Test direct'
files = os.listdir(path)
i = 151

for file in files:
    os.rename(os.path.join(path, file), os.path.join(path, str(i)+'.TIF'))
    i = i+1
```

Answer (score 2):

Simply by writing that concatenation expression.  If I understand your details correctly, your new loop body would be

```
new_name = file + " 17-" + str(i) + ".TIF"
os.rename(os.path.join(path, file), 
          os.path.join(path, new_name) )
i += 1
```

This would change file "ABC" into file "ABC 17-151.TIF"; the next would contain "17-152", and so on.

**FACEPALM**

`file` is a built-in type.  Change the loop index.

```
for fname in files:
    new_name = fname + " 17-" + str(i) + ".TIF"
    os.rename(os.path.join(path, fname), new_name)
    i += 1
```

Comment: Is `file` still a string?  Try `print type(file) just ahead of the `rename` command.  On my Python, `listdir` returns a list of strings.

Comment: That is seriously strange: `file` is a generic *type*??  I can't reproduce this with your code.  I've tried my solution in my local directory, and it works as expected, giving `<type 'str>` for the variable type.  What Python?  Did you cut & paste this code back into your environment to ensure we're running the same stuff?  All I did was to replace your path with "." and disable the `rename` command.

Comment: `fname` is defined in the `for` statement.

Comment: Where are you stuck?  That error message looks quite specific.

Comment: So remove it.  If it's at the end, just grab the slice up until then with `name[:-3]`.  If it's in the middle, use `name.replace(".TIF", "")` -- which works in either case.

Comment: Nearly there, sorry to be such a newb. Now I get NameError: name 'name' is not defined

Comment: Use whatever variable is holding the file name.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand Prune's suggestion above, which I obviously don't, it would look like:

```
import os
path = 'C:\Users\dcs\Desktop\Test direct'
files = os.listdir(path)
i = 151

#The part that I want to strip the extensions from
for file in files:
    new_name = file[:-3]

#The part that words correctly (thanks Prune)
for fname in files:
    new_name = fname + " 17-" + str(i) + ".TIF"
    os.rename(os.path.join(path, fname), new_name)
    i += 1
```

However the first part, meant to strip the file of it's extension isn't working.